# lvmcache/dm-cache writeback cache full performance

Tags: linux, cache, lvm, ssd, dm-cache

I have a SSD writeback cache in front of a HDD, set up through lvmcache (so a dm-cache). When the cache LV is not full (`Data%` column in `lvs` < 100.00%), writes go to the cache device (monitored via `dstat`). However, when the cache LV is full (`Data%` = 100.00%), writes go directly to the HDD, essentially becoming a writethrough cache. Blocks do not get evicted from the SSD cache, even after some time, and performance drops. When I try reading recently read data from the cached LV, reads are from the SSD, so I assume the entire SSD has now become a read cache. Is this expected behavior for dm-cache's write cache, even in writeback mode? Is there no reserved space for writes? This seems like quite a poor design as essentially users can only write one cache LV's worth of data before the cache becomes a writethrough cache.

My understanding is that dm-cache uses the [mq eviction algorithm](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix01/full_papers/zhou/zhou_html/node9.html), but that only applies to read caching and thus is irrelevant to the write caching issue I am observing.

Is there a way to reserve space for a write cache, or use both a dm-writecache (which I understand will not do any read caching) and a dm-cache at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dm-cache` is a "slow moving" cache: many read/write misses are required to promote a block, especially when promoting a new block means to *demote* an already-cached one.

The fixed block-based nature of `dm-cache`, coupled with no reserved write-only area, means that many writes to the same non-cached blocks are required to trigger a block promotion/replacement. However, this also implies that the kernel pagecache is not "absorbing" these multiple missing writes, merging them in a single write to the underlying block devices.

In other words, you are probably seeing the combined effect of the kernel pagecache (which absorbs and merges writes) *and* the reluctance of `dm-cache` to promote first-missed blocks.

If you want to reserve some device/space to write cache only, you can tap into [`dm-writecache`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/writecache.txt) (and the usual [`lvmcache`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html))

**Additional information:**

`dm-cache` does block promotion/demotion tracking access hits/misses. At first, you have an empty cache with all I/O directed to the origin (slow) device. So when you issue a, say, 4K read it will access the underlying slow device, with `dm-cache` tracking the miss. After some other misses to the *same cache block* (default 32K), then *entire* cache block is copied to the fast device. If you now writes to the cached blocks, your write will be cached. If, however, your write is for an *uncached block*, it goes straight to the origin (slow) device. After some other uncached writes, `dm-cache` will finally allocate the entire cache block (remember, 32K by default) copying the original data to the cache device. At this point, new reads/writes can be served from the cache. Demotion is simple: when a new block must be promoted, the oldest block is discarded/flushed.

In other words, for write to be cached, the corresponding cache segment must be allocated and the backing data must be copied on the cache device (allocate-on-write). To limit bandwidth usage between origin and cache device, this copy is only done after many misses (ie: a single miss will *not* promote a block). Note that reading many times the same uncached block will *not* work, as the kernel pagecache will simply provide the cached block by itself.

`dm-writecache` works differently, being more similar to a traditional RAID controller writeback cache. It caches *all* writes, ignoring reads. It can almost be considered a "write-only L2 pagecache", where dirty pages are "swapped" waiting for the slow device to catch up. To use it, you need to partition your fast devices between `dm-cache` (which, at this point, must be run as `writethrough` cache) and `dm-writecache`, or to dedicate different devices to them. I *never* tried doing that via LVM, and I suspect that the tooling will prevent you to nest/stack two different cache modules. However, you can try it via direct `dmsetup` commands.

Comment: "means that many writes to the same non-cached blocks are required to trigger a block promotion/replacement."

I do not understand the concept of caching a write block and promoting/demoting it. Writes are essentially buffered in write caches (such as dm-writecache) and demote other blocks in aggressive read caches if the write is counted as an access. Could you elaborate on this more?

"If you want to reserve some device/space to write cache only, you can tap into dm-writecache (and the usual lvmcache)"

How would I do this? This would entail having two caches on one LV right?

Comment: @AlbertT I've edited my answer with the required info